# JavaScript which calculates the number of days by today, from user selected date

Tags: javascript, forms, function, date, input

I have this code bellow which provides user selected date. I want to calculate how many days have been gone by today and the result to be something like that: "Today's the 2541st */example/* day of blablabla...". Also i want the result to be returned, wherever i want. I'm novice in JavaScript, please explain to me how to be done my idea. Thanks in advance.

```
function IncrementDay(month,year)
{
var lastDay = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
var nDay=document.getElementById("bday").value;
++nDay;
if (nDay > lastDay) {
    nDay =1
}
document.getElementById("bday").value=nDay;
}

function IncrementMonth()
{
var nMonth = document.getElementById("bmonth").value;
++nMonth;
if (nMonth==13) {
    nMonth =1
}
document.getElementById("bmonth").value=nMonth;
}
</SCRIPT>

<head>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="0" id="bday" onClick="javascript:IncrementDay(document.getElementById('bmonth').value, document.getElementById('byear').value);" />
<input type="button" value="0" id="bmonth" onClick="javascript:IncrementMonth();" />
<input type="text" value="0" id="byear" />

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var cDate= new Date();
var cDay = cDate.getDate();
var cMonth = cDate.getMonth();
var cYear = cDate.getFullYear();

++cMonth;

document.getElementById("bday").value=cDay;
document.getElementById("bmonth").value=cMonth;
document.getElementById("byear").value=cYear;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont quite get the example you gave but is **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/4XLPD/)** kinda stuff you want?

Comment: for example you select your birthday, push a button and it calculates how many days you live. Its something like that but not exactly.

Comment: So its how many days gone not from today to some date in the future but from a past date to today. Like [THIS ONE](http://jsfiddle.net/u3BBq/) ?

Comment: yes, but selecting the date like i've shown in my code. Is it posible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/MSftg/)**

Comment: In fiddle, it doesnt work for me. Even the day and month button dont change when they're clicked. They stay with value 0.